# Is there any reason for an index to contain the primary key?

Tags: sql-server, index-tuning

I inherited a project using SQL Server 2005.  Recently there were some performance problems and I started looking at the indexes, and found

```
_dta_index_survey_25_135059617__K1_K10_K19:
    id ASC, sent_date ASC, group_id ASC
```

and

```
_dta_index_survey_21_364632442__K18_K1_K2_K9:
    group_id ASC, id ASC, campaign_id ASC, sent_date ASC
```

which appears to be generated by some kind of automatic performance tuning tool.  I think SQL Server comes with something like that but I'm not familiar with it.

Anyway, `id` is the primary key, and what I'm trying to understand here is how it could possibly be beneficial to include the primary key within a secondary index... because you have to have the leftmost pieces of information to use an index and if you know `id` then you've got the row anyway.

Can someone explain why a tool would have generated these indexes and if there's any point in keeping them?

Just because the indexes are getting used doesn't mean they're a good design.  SQL Server is using the *wrong* indexes lately, and I'm trying to determine why. More specifically, queries against this table that ran in milliseconds a month ago are now taking multiple seconds.  The table is huge (4M rows), and growing steadily, but at the same pace it's been going at for years.

Almost every query joins across `group_id` or `campaign_id`.  Often both.  The application almost never specifically selects or sorts by the PK, but I could see how `ID` could be useful when comparing or merging lists of `ID`s within the database engine.  ... But `id` is also an identity column, and an index holds lists of row ids, so it still seems redundant to have the `ID` in the key when it's also in the index "buckets".  And the additional fields could still be covered by the index without being part of the key.

I discovered that `(id, sent_date, group_id)` hardly ever gets read.  Meanwhile `(group_id, id, campaign_id, sent_date)` is one of the hottest indexes.  Next I found that an index which I thought was pretty reasonable `(campaign_id, sent_date, group_id, id)` also has a `index_columns_include` of every other column in the table, and occupies more space than the primary clustered index on `id`!  (but it's also pretty hot...)  Surely I can replace it with a simple `(campaign_id, sent_date, group_id)`?

Comment: There's certainly no point having any key columns to the right of the `id` that I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuning tools use a shotgun approach.  They put all combinations of indexes as a hypothetical indexes. A hypothetical index does not create any of the indexes but it certain type of hypothetical does keep stats on them by how many reads and writes would have taken place.  Then the tuning tool gets the hypothetical with the top stats and gives them to you and destroys all hypothetical.

So someone put in indexes from a tuning tool, but I would prefer to get the actual statistics that are kept since the last time SQL Server was restarted.  Below is sample code to get the statistics.  Look at total reads and compare to total writes.  More writes than reads is bad.  If I find an index with zero reads, I drop them and I have never had to put them back.

1. What is the clustered index?
2. How many indexes?  Anything over 5 indexes is usually to many.

---

```
SELECT distinct
  DB_Name(DB_id()) as DbName
  , oo.name AS object_name
  , stat.user_updates AS [Total Writes]
  , stat.user_seeks + stat.user_scans + stat.user_lookups AS [Total Reads]
  , stat.user_updates - (stat.user_seeks + stat.user_scans + stat.user_lookups) AS [Difference]
  , partition1.Rows
  , partition1.SizeMB
  , iib.name AS index_name
  , iib.type_desc
  , FilegroupName = fg.groupname
  , ISNULL(IndexColumns.index_columns_key, '---') AS index_columns_key
  , ISNULL(IndexColumns.index_columns_include, '---') AS index_columns_include
  , iib.is_primary_key
  , iib.is_unique
  , iib.is_unique_constraint
  , iib.is_hypothetical
  , STATS_DATE ( oo.[object_id] , iib.index_id ) as IndexCreatedDate
  , iib.fill_factor
FROM sys.objects                      AS oo  WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN sys.schemas                      AS ss  WITH (NOLOCK) ON oo.schema_id=ss.schema_id
JOIN sys.indexes                      AS iib WITH (NOLOCK) ON oo.object_id=iib.object_id
left JOIN sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS stat WITH (NOLOCK) ON stat.[object_id] = iib.[object_id] AND iib.index_id = stat.index_id
left JOIN sys.partitions              AS pp WITH (NOLOCK) ON iib.object_id = pp.OBJECT_ID AND iib.index_id = pp.index_id
left JOIN sys.allocation_units        AS aa WITH (NOLOCK) ON pp.partition_id = aa.container_id
left JOIN sys.sysfilegroups           AS fg WITH (NOLOCK) ON fg.groupid = aa.data_space_id
left JOIN (
 SELECT
   object_id, index_id, SUM(row_count) AS Rows,
   CONVERT(numeric(19,3), CONVERT(numeric(19,3), SUM(in_row_reserved_page_count+lob_reserved_page_count+row_overflow_reserved_page_count))/CONVERT(numeric(19,3), 128)) AS SizeMB
 FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats WITH (NOLOCK)
 GROUP BY object_id, index_id
 ) AS partition1 ON iib.object_id=partition1.object_id AND iib.index_id=partition1.index_id
 CROSS APPLY
 (
    SELECT
    (
      SELECT sys.columns.name + ', '
      FROM sys.index_columns WITH (NOLOCK)
      JOIN sys.columns WITH (NOLOCK) ON sys.index_columns.column_id=sys.columns.column_id
                       AND sys.index_columns.object_id=sys.columns.object_id
      WHERE sys.index_columns.is_included_column=0
      AND iib.object_id=sys.index_columns.object_id AND iib.index_id=sys.index_columns.index_id
      ORDER BY key_ordinal
      FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS index_columns_key,
    (
      SELECT sys.columns.name + ', '
      FROM sys.index_columns WITH (NOLOCK)
      JOIN sys.columns WITH (NOLOCK) ON sys.index_columns.column_id=sys.columns.column_id
                       AND sys.index_columns.object_id=sys.columns.object_id
      WHERE sys.index_columns.is_included_column=1
      AND iib.object_id=sys.index_columns.object_id AND iib.index_id=sys.index_columns.index_id
      ORDER BY index_column_id
      FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS index_columns_include
 ) AS IndexColumns
WHERE stat.database_id = DB_ID()
and oo.is_ms_shipped = 0
and oo.name not in ( 'sysdiagrams' )
and iib.is_hypothetical = 0
ORDER BY oo.name, iib.name
```

The index you mention will probably work.  But I prefer to put an index in as an experiment and use the script above to get factual measurements as to how good an index is.

Answer (score 10):

You are right to be suspicious of the two indexes that you listed in your question, but there are a few narrow use cases for including the primary key in an index as a key column. By default SQL Server will make your primary key into a clustered key which is the more important concept for performance for this question, so instead if referring to primary keys to answer I'll refer to clustered keys instead.

For the index on `id`, `sent_date`, and `group_id`, queries that only select those columns may benefit because the index will be a covering index for that query. You say that if you know `id` then you've got the row but what you really have is a very efficient way to read all of the data in data pages for that row. Suppose your (rowstore) table just has a clustered index on the `id` column. Consider the following query:

```
SELECT id, sent_date, group_id
FROM your_table
ORDER BY id;
```

SQL Server is likely to perform a clustered index scan to satisfy that data. All of the data from the data pages will be read which includes columns in the table that aren't referenced by the query.

After creating the `_dta_index_survey_25_135059617__K1_K10_K19` index then SQL Server will be able to satisfy that query with an index scan on the new index. It is possible that the index will take up less pages than the table so that could be more efficient from an IO perspective. For example, suppose that you had a `VARCHAR(2000)` column that was heavily populated with data. That column will be included in the data pages for the clustered index but will not be included in the nonclustered index. That means that satisfying the query using the nonclustered index could incur fewer logical reads.

Note that `sent_date` and `group_id` aren't useful as key columns for this example. They could be `INCLUDED` columns for the same benefit. Note that without the `ORDER BY` clause an index on just `sent_date` and `group_id` would also be a covering index, so including the `id` column wouldn't be useful for that example without `ORDER BY`.

That index could also be marginally useful if your clustered key was defined as `id DESC` (`id ASC` is the default). SQL Server cannot do backwards clustered index scans in parallel, but the following query could be run in parallel with a scan on `_dta_index_survey_25_135059617__K1_K10_K19`:

```
SELECT id
FROM your_table
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Again, the key columns on `sent_date` and `group_id` aren't useful for this query, but the query optimizer could use the first column of the defined index. I cannot think of a query that benefits from all three key columns.

It is more difficult to think of queries that would benefit from the index on `group_id`, `id`, `campaign_id`, and `sent_date`. Assuming that the clustered key is defined as `id ASC`, I believe that `ORDER BY group_id, id, campaign_id, sent_date` can be satisfied by an index on just `group_id` because `id` is a unique clustering key and that index will be created in `group_id` then `id` order. As before, you could benefit if your index on id is sorted in a different order than the clustering key on `id`.

I suspect there are also some data distributions that could benefit from the `_dta_index_survey_21_364632442__K18_K1_K2_K9` index when filtering on both group_id and id, even though id is a unique clustered key. Suppose that each data page in the table contains 2 rows and half the rows in the table have `group_id = 1`. In theory, SQL Server could use that index to satisfy the following query:

```
SELECT group_id, id, campaign_id, sent_date
FROM your_table
WHERE group_id = 1 AND id IN (1,3,5,7,9,...);
```

and possibly do less IO than using the clustered index. However, I do not know if the query optimizer would actually do this.

In summary, there are some some corner cases with covering indexes and sort orders which could benefit from the indexes that you listed in the question. However, in my experience it will be pretty unlikely those indexes will provide a noticeable (or even any) benefit for your workload. If those indexes do happen to provide a benefit it's likely that there will be smaller indexes that could provide the same benefit.

Comment: Another type of query that might benefit from the 2nd index would be joining to another table and a specific group_id (that appears in a large proportion of the rows): `SELECT y.campaign_id, y.sent_date, t.* FROM your_table AS y JOIN another_table AS t ON y.id = t.y_id WHERE y.group_id = 1;` Still, a very corner case, as you say.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the index DMV's to figure out which indexes are currently being used or not used.

second it could be a case where the server is being used for OLTP and reporting which can result in needing a lot of indexes